# Product of exponential of matrices

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Suppose that $e^Xe^Y=e^Ye^X$.

It is known that, in general, this equality does not imply $XY=YX$. However, an exercise in Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory [Page 154, Exercise 7.6.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=SuR5OAgxyDIC&q=log%20multiplicative%20property#v=snippet&q=log%20multiplicative%20property&f=false) asks to show that $XY=YX$ (My understanding from section 7.6 in the book is that, this exercise requires the implicit assumption that the norms of all matrices involved are small).
I would appreciate possibly different hints/solutions for doing this problem.

**Edit:**
Fortunately, I could add the the link to the exercise through googlebooks. Please follow the link for the precise statement of the exercise and the context in which it appears.

Comment: A hint would be to look at the simplest pair of matrices that do not commute.

Comment: @Somos Is that a hint for proving the statement? (We need to show that $X$ and $Y$ commute.)

Comment: The crux is that if $X$ and $Y$ do commute then $e^Xe^Y=e^Ye^X$, but, as you state, the converse do not hold. However, the matrices may be close to commutative in some sense. In particular look at matrices that are close to the identity matrix.

Comment: Perhaps the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula would help?

Answer (score 1):

"Small norms" may mean that the sought equality holds only approximately.
$$
e^{X} e^{Y} = (I + X + \mbox{(negligible)}) (I + Y + \mbox{(negligible)}) = I + X + Y + XY + \mbox{(negligible)}
$$
Similarly,
$$
e^{Y} e^{X} = I + X + Y + YX + \mbox{(negligible)}
$$
Since you asked only for hints, I'll stop here.

Comment: Thanks avs. I think by inequality you mean "equality." The problem is in fact asking for an exact equality: $XY=YX$. Small norm assumption is there to facilitate applications of log function...

Comment: Yes, I did mean "equality", thanks for catching.:)  Not sure the exact equality would hold as the problem is stated.  Also, I think your problem is related to Problem 1 on page 124 of this book: {https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=arnold+ordinary+differential+equations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd-6LDn-jTAhVEbiYKHVW6Dx0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=Lie&f=false}

Comment: Problem 1 states that the bracket of two vector fields is a vector field... I'm not sure I see any relation between that problem and the question above.

Comment: It cannot be precise for any small norm matrix, simply because you can divide X and Y by any number, large as you want, and they shall have small norm.

Comment: @Omry Can you write down an **explicit** counterexample to the statement where the norms can be made arbitrarily small?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the commutators, you've got
$$
0=[e^X,e^Y] \\
=[1+X+\frac{1}{2}X^2+O(X^3),1+Y+\frac{1}{2}Y^2+O(Y^3)] \\
=[X,Y]+\frac{1}{2}[X^2,Y]+\frac{1}{2}[X,Y^2]+O(X^3,Y^3),
$$
which implies that *either* $X$ and $Y$ commute, or else the commutator of $X$ and $Y$ is $O(X^2,Y^2)$, since the remaining terms are all at least that small and need to cancel it out.  If you want to be precise about what you're proving, I believe you can show that if $[e^{cX},e^{cY}]=0$ whenever $|c| < \varepsilon$ (for some positive $\varepsilon$), then $[X,Y]=0$.  (In other words, $e^{cX}$ and $e^{cY}$ can "accidentally" commute for some values of $c$, but if they do so for arbitrarily small values of $c$, then $X$ and $Y$ must themselves commute.)